# React/Redux: Where to put jQuery event handlers in component awaiting async data

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux

When I read the ReactJS docs I understand that the best lifecycle method to put redux action calls is `componentDidMount` but I find it hard to do any jquery work in that lifecycle method:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAsyncLoaded: false
        }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        let {getData} = nextProps.someData;
        let {hasSuccess, isLoading} = getData;

        if (!isLoading && hasSuccess) {
            return {
                isAsyncLoaded: true
            }
        } else {
            return {
                isAsyncLoaded: false
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getSomeData();
        $('p').css('color', 'red');
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.isAsyncLoaded) return null;
        return (
            <p>{this.props.someData.data}</p>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        someData: state.someData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getSomeData})(App);
```

Here the jquery `$('p').css('color', 'red');` part doesn't find the `<p>` element because `isAsyncLoaded` is not true and `render` function returns `null`.

My question is how can I solve this problem without introducing a container-view, (parent-child) component relationship to my app?

Comment: Why are you even involving jQuery in the first place? jQuery should have no place in a react way of doing things. It goes against the antipattern.

Comment: I understand what you mean but suppose I have an important plugin that I use that depends on jquery. And which has no similar react counterpart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply jquery code in `componentDidUpdate()`

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // execute code only when at the moment when async code is first rendered
  if (prevState.isAsyncLoaded === false && this.state.isAsyncLoaded === true) {
    // Do your jQuery stuff here
    $(this.mountPoint).find(...);
  }
}
```

live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ee57nm

Comment: While this is a viable alternative, I'm usually against these design decisions as it makes it harder to debug. What happens when another programmer down the line adds another fetch statement which updates the data? `isAsyncLoaded` is already true, so it wont flip, and the jQuery code is never executed. New event handlers wont bind. The ideal place to add this should be as this async component is being rendered.

Comment: @FrankerZ well we need to start from the point that using jQuery with react is an anti-pattern. This solution is just an escape hatch.

Comment: I still insist that if I have a mandatory jquery plugin that I wanna use I'll **have to** do this sort of integration.

Comment: @BarışÜrüm that's a pragmatic approach. Use jQ till you find/create a replacement for a given plugin since native react implementation will be much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few notes before I get into this: Using event handlers like jQuery is usually an anti-pattern in React. It can cause unintended side effects on your DOM, that should ideally be handled entirely through controlled components within react.

If you need to use jQuery though (For a quick/dirty plugin, or things like that), I recommend using a separate component. When that component gets mounted, it fires off a [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) event, which you can hook and fire off your jQuery code:

```
class MyJqueryComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.mountPoint = React.createRef();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // Do your jQuery stuff here
        $(this.mountPoint).find(...);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <p ref={this.mountPoint}>{this.props.data}</p>
        );
    }
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAsyncLoaded: false
        }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        let {getData} = nextProps.someData;
        let {hasSuccess, isLoading} = getData;

        if (!isLoading && hasSuccess) {
            return {
                isAsyncLoaded: true
            }
        } else {
            return {
                isAsyncLoaded: false
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getSomeData();
        $('p').css('color', 'red');
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.isAsyncLoaded) return null;
        return (
            <p><MyJqueryComponent data={this.props.someData.data} /></p>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        someData: state.someData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getSomeData})(App);
```

Comment: I can't see how this differs from creating a container- view hierarchy and using jquery only with child component. It looks dirtier and overengineered.

Comment: @BarışÜrüm Welcome to the reasoning why this is an anti-pattern. :P